# Wired ethernet disconnect after first webpage

Tags: linux-mint, ethernet

I have an issue with my wired ethernet :
After i plug it, the internet connection seem to be ok (ping at google.com --> OK), **but when i go to a website, after loading the first page, the connection is broken.

Config : Linux mint 18.2

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   produit: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
   fabriquant: Qualcomm Atheros
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:04:00.0
   nom logique: eth0
   version: 08
   numéro de série: 10:bf:48:28:20:4a
   taille: 1Gbit/s
   capacité: 1Gbit/s
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   ressources: irq:30 mémoire:f7800000-f783ffff portE/S:d000(taille=128)
```

**ifconfig** show increasing number of erros in packet, and ping doesn't respond anyway.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:bf:48:28:20:4a  
          inet adr:192.168.1.11  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::443a:ead3:32f:d0f7/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:3450 erreurs:2036 :0 overruns:2036 frame:0
          TX packets:862 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:1067220 (1.0 MB) Octets transmis:138864 (138.8 KB)
          Interruption:19
```

On the same laptop, I have a Windows boot and the wired ethernet works fine. Wifi connection is okay on both Windows and Linux Mint.

Comment: We will need more info (don't know what). It won't be related to loading a page. You seem to have a layer 2 problem, but loading a page is at level 4 or 5 or 6 ish. A page load can involve many connections.

Comment: Does `dmesg` give any related messages?

Comment: hi,  I don't think there is any related messages

`dmesg`


`[ 1488.478859] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full

[ 1488.479182] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=150&t=226626&p=1196004&hilit=AR8161#p1196004

Set MTU to 8192 with

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 8192
```